# Jeditable css hover issue

Tags: jquery, css, jeditable

```
$('.editable').editable('/echo/html/', {
    callback: function (value) {
        $(this).data('bgcolor', $(this).css('background-color'));
        if (value == this.revert) {
            $(this).animate({
                color: "red"
            }, 400);
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: $(this).data('bgcolor'),
                color: "black"
            }, 400);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                color: '#91c83e'
            }, 400);
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: $(this).data('bgcolor'),
                color: "black"
            }, 600);
        }
    },
    name: 'value',
    width: '50px',
    height: '16px',
    onblur: 'submit'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qrA6y/1/

I am having a css issue with Jeditable, when I select and the box is shown, and when I unselect (therefore returning the input box back to `<tr>`, it sets the background colour to that of when it was set)

I.e if you unselect the input box by selecteing somehwere else on the same row (keeping the row highlighted in yellow) and then move mouse away, the background remains yellow.

similarly if you unselect the input box by selecting OFF the row, the background sets to white and when returning to hover on the row, the hover colour no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding the hover in the css style, something like this:

```
<style>
.editable:hover { #91c83e; }
</style>
```